# What happens if two mySQL queries both try to lock the same row at the same time?

Tags: mysql, locking, semaphore

So this isn't exactly my strong suit, but here's my basic understanding of the situation:

If two threads of the same application both try to execute the same query at the same time, MySQL will experience an error.  You prevent this by locking the table (or row) before writing to it.  But what if the *locking* requests happen simultaneously?

e.g. you have a table like:

```
#my_table
---------------
| key | value |
---------------
|  1  |  foo  |
---------------
|  2  |  bar  |
---------------
```

Then I write a query in my application that does something like

```
LOCK TABLES my_table WRITE;
UPDATE my_table SET value = RAND() WHERE key = 2;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

and by some miracle two instances of this application process fire in the exact same millisecond (nanosecond?) what would happen?  Does one of the `LOCK` requests block the other?  And, if so, how does MySQL decide with one blocks and which one proceeds.  Will the second `LOCK` still go through after the first releases?

It's an InnoDB table if that matters, so I think there's autolocking.

Answer (score 2):

Whichever session issues the query first gets the lock first. The other session will block until the lock is released, then proceed normally.

They can't happen simultaneously. The database engine prevents that.

InnoDB's "automatic" locking is a bit more granular (down to the row), though there are also table locks happening. Thanks to [MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control), select queries in InnoDB aren't normally blocked, which is different from MyISAM's table locking scheme (and manually write locking tables as your query illustrates).

You can fine tune what happens by setting InnoDB's [isolation level](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html).

Comment: How does the database engine prevent that?  That's really the heart of my question.  Does it just pick one at random? (there is no "first" in this scenario)

Comment: There's a global [mutex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) for transactions. It's not random. It's first come, first serve.

Comment: What do you mean *first*?  There is no first.  MySQL might act like one is first, but in real world terms, there is no first.

Comment: Click the link in the previous comment and read about mutexes.

Comment: I am not replying in this thread again.  You are clearly ignoring my question.

Comment: What processor are you talking about that doesn't have atomic operations? Please explain how "there is no first".